# How to reuse TCP socket python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, error-handling

## What I want to do

I would like to use again sTCP.connect() with a different IP and PORT

## My problem

In the next interaction of while (when I have a different IP and PORT than the last one), I get an Error: **"This connection is already in use"**
What can I do in order to make it work? 
The socket is declared before the while loop. For clearance I'll only show the while loop:

```
while y != numero_de_lineas:
        print "Interaccion numero", y

        if reintentar == 1:
            print y
            reintentar = 0


        tupla = (str(iplista[y]),int(portlista[y]))
        sUDP.sendto(mensaje1,tupla)
        try:
            if reintentar != 1:  #si estoy reintentando no quiero otro timeout
                sUDP.settimeout(time_out)
                respuesta1 , address1 = sUDP.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)

            #si todo va bien tengo respuesta1
            #print(respuesta1) #recibo ni ok ni no
            if (respuesta1 == "ok") or (reintentar != 1):




                sTCP.connect((iplista[y],int(portlista[y])))  #SE CONECTA N VECES, HAY QUE ACCEPTAR OTRA CONEXION CON .accept()
                contenido_fichero = fichero.read()  #lo que hay dentro de ./fichero.txt
                sTCP.send(contenido_fichero)
                try:

                    sTCP.settimeout(time_out_TCP) #esperamos 10 segundos
                    respuesta2 = sTCP.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
                    #LIBERAMOS LA CONEXION TCP

                    #print(respuesta2) #recibo transferdone
                    #si recibe respuesta1 y respuesta2 paramos
                    #empezamos con el calculo de la huella con el server aceptado iplista[y],portlista[y]
                    huella_md5 = md5.new() #creamos la huella
                    huella_md5.update(contenido_fichero) #actualicamos su contenido (le podemos meter mas strings despues)
                    huella_md5_calculada = huella_md5.hexdigest() #huella en string



                    sUDP.sendto(huella_md5_calculada,tupla)
                    try:
                        sUDP.settimeout(time_out_TCP) #porque son 10 segundos
                        respuesta3 , address3 = sUDP.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)

                        if respuesta3 == "md5sum ok":
                            print "Copia de fichero en servidor",iplista[y],"correcta"

                        if respuesta3 == "md5sum error":
                            print "Error en la copia del fichero en el servidor",iplista[y],"Se vuelve a intentar" #REINTENTAR
                            reintentar = 1



                    except socket.timeout:
                        print "Error en la copia del fichero en el servidor",iplista[y],". Finalizado el intento"


                except socket.timeout:
                    print "Error en la transferencia con el servidor",str(iplista[y])
            if respuesta1 == "no":
                print "Error. El servidor",iplista[y],"no acepta el fichero"

        except socket.timeout:
            print "Error: no hay respuesta por parte del servidor",  iplista[y] , "en el puerto", portlista[y]
            #if y == (numero_de_lineas-1):  #-1 porque para y el cero cuenta
                #sys.exit()  #si todos fallaron al conectar udp nos salimos
```

## Edit:

This is the socket declaration (it is located before the while loop)

```
 try: #tenemos que crear el socket tcp en cada interaccion porque sino ya esta en uso
    sUDP = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)     #UDP
    sTCP = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)    #TCP
except socket.error :
    print "Error al crear socket TCP"
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner here you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot connect twice on the same `socket` instance. You have to create a new `socket` object each time, i.e. you need

```
sTCP = socket.socket(...)
```

each time before you call `.connect(...)`.

Don't forget to `.close()` and/or `.shutdown()` the old socket instance.

Comment: So lets suppose I declare sTCP in the loop and I do .connect() in the loop.... Do I have to put sTCP.close() or sTCP.shutdown() at the end of the loop in order to make it work in the next interaction of the while? @freakish

Comment: @GinésDíaz: you don't have to close the socket, but you should to ensure that resources are properly released, just as you would a file.

Comment: @mhawke so thats my question, how can I release the TCP connection to use it again with a different IP?

Comment: @GinésDíaz: sorry, strictly speaking you do not _have_ to close the socket, but you should close it with `socket.shutdown()` and `socket.close()` because it is good practice to (so both local and remote resources can be released). You can create a new socket and bind it to the same variable, in which case the original socket object should become eligible for garbage collection, and eventually cleaned up - but that's unpredictable and the remote peer might not be informed that it's connection is lost.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you are using a different destination (IP, port) pair because `y` is never changed. The address is given by:

```
(iplista[y],int(portlista[y]))
```

So if `y` never changes the same address will be used. Because the connection is still open from the previous loop, a new connection attempt fails.

Perhaps you should be incrementing `y` in the loop.

You should also be closing the connection once you are done with it to ensure that resources are properly released. Use [`sTCP.shutdown()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socket.html#socket.socket.shutdown) followed by [`sTCP.close()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close) for that. Then create a new socket for the next connection (N.B. that means that you need to create the socket *inside* the loop).

Comment: Im sorry I forgot to include y = y+1 at the end of the loop , but thank you!